# Generating dynamic query in spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a native `Mysql` query

```
select tl_id,c_name,m_name,u_first_name,t_name, 
tl_logged_at,tl_minutes,tl_description
from users inner join clients on u_id=c_frn_owner_id
inner join matters on m_frn_client_id = c_id
inner join tasks on t_frn_matter_id = m_id
inner join task_logs on tl_frn_task_id = t_id
where c_id =2 and m_id=4 and t_id= 3 and u_id = 4
```

for which I can write `JPQL` instead of native query. But how to get the same query using `JPA Specification`, since the columns or fields in the `where` conditions `c_id`, `m_id`, `t_id` and `u_id` are optionals. They are filter options provided to the user.

Generation of native query can be done using `if` conditions. But they are prone to typo and `SQL Injections`.

The documentation of `JPASpecification` has no informations related to joining multiple tables.

[Spring Official JPA Specification Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.1.0.M2/reference/html/#specifications)

I am very new to `JPASpecification` so any guidance will be valuable.

Answer (score 0):

> JPA 2 introduces a criteria API that you can use to build queries
>   programmatically.

If you use JPA 2 and you wanted to create dynamic query, I think you should look at the [Criteria API](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa/jpa_criteria_api.htm) to build dynamic queries. Or you can use JpaSpecificationExecutor(I haven't tried, yet.) Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280708/filtering-database-rows-with-spring-data-jpa-and-spring-mvc) related question.

Some useful links attached:

1. [JPA Specifications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48679030/6424383)
2. [JPA Criteria Api](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/criteria)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the querydsl project, I use it extensively in a mid size ERP and hasn't disappointed until now.

http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html/

for dynamic where clause: you can use `com.querydsl.core.BooleanBuilder`

So when you have querydsl in place, you can first generate your where clause like the following.

```
QEmployee employee = QEmployee.employee;
 BooleanBuilder dynamicWhere = new BooleanBuilder();
 if(true) { //Any condition
     dynamicWhere.and(employee.name.equalsIgnoreCase("someName"));
 }
 if(true){
     dynamicWhere.and(employee.age.gt(18));
 }
```

and then you can write your query like the following.

```
queryFactory.selectFrom(employee)
    //joins, group by, order by goes here
    .where(dynamicWhere)
    .fetch();
```